# Why doesn't Mozilla release 64-bit versions of Firefox?

Tags: firefox, 64-bit

Mozilla releases 64 bit nightly builds of every version . Why doesn't it release official 64 bit build of the same version when it reaches stable state ?

Comment: I guess you will have to ask Mozilla.

Comment: What benefit will there be? What costs would there be? Surely the problems far outweigh the benefits? I've been using 64-bit windows since 2005, but even I can't yet seen the need. The nightly builds are simply keeping x64 on the back-burner for when they might be needed in future.

Comment: Update: https://blog.mozilla.org/futurereleases/2015/12/15/firefox-64-bit-for-windows-available/

Answer (score 6):

The main reason for a long time: there were no 64 bit Flash and Java plugins.

Comment: This is the same reason both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Internet Explorer are installed on a 64-bit Windows system, and that the 64-bit version cannot be set as default.

Comment: Also the reason why it's better to use 32 bit Office, rather than 64 bit Office.